# Importing JSON array of arrays into Excel

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I'm trying to import a JSON file with the following format into Excel:

```
[
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8]
]
```

I want to get a spreadsheet with 2 rows and 4 columns, where each row contains the contents of the inner array as separate column values, e.g.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

Although this would seem to be an easy problem to solve, I can't seem to find the right PowerQuery syntax, or locate an existing answer that covers this scenario.  I can easily import as a single column with 8 values, but can't seem to split the inner array into separate columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the JSON looks like

```
[
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8]
]
```

then this code in Powerquery

```
let Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\j.json")),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Column1], each Text.From(_)),",")),
ColumnTitles = List.Transform({1 .. List.Max(Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "count", each List.Count(Text.PositionOfAny([Custom],{","},Occurrence.All))+1)[count])}, each "Column." & Text.From(_)),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), ColumnTitles),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Column1"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

generates

[image]

It converts the JSON to a list of lists, converts to a table of lists, expands the list to be text with commas, then expands that into columns after dynamically creating column names for the new columns by counting the max number of commas